# how we will know on the server side if the peer still connected using Nodejs WebRTC

Tags: node.js, websocket, webrtc

I am using WebRTC to make a audio, video and chat application. How on the server side we can check if the peer is still connected.

Actually, I want to check before making audio/video call that the other user end is still connected. I am able to maintain Presence (i.e online/offline) when user logs in or logs out of the application.

Suppose, the network connection drops or got disconnected, I am not able to get any information on the server side. If I can get, then I can communicate to rest of the peers connected.

So, need help how to get the information if the peer is still connected or not. I am using Nodejs and WebRTC in my application.

Answer (score 2):

[Socket.IO](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms) has a concept of 'rooms' that makes it very handy for building WebRTC signaling servers, and a `disconnect` event fired when a user disconnects. You can also set up a custom event to be emited when, for example, a user stops a video stream or leaves a page.

You might want to take a look at the codelab at [bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab](http://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab), which uses Socket.IO for signaling. (Apologies, once again, for shameless self promotion!)

Comment: Hi Sam, It works fine for me for the above as you have mentioned. I am also using room concept. The problem what I am stating here is, suppose Jeet wants to connect Sam, and Sam shows online in Jeet's contact list as Sam is logged in on his machine. Now what happens, due to network problem or What Sam does is he plugs out his network cable from his machibe. Then, he is offline, but in this case the disconnect event is not fired, thus he still show online on Jeet contact list. Which is wrong.

Comment: Got it. I guess for this you might be forced to use polling. The server app could expect an 'I'm still here!' message from the client every few seconds and, if this wasn't received, would remove the client from the room.

Comment: Yes, Just wondering about the server load. When there will be good user base using the application concurrently.

Comment: Agree that server load could become a problem with this method -- and it requires continual network requests from the client. Not sure how you can continually check if a client is online without some kind of continual polling though.

Comment: Socket.io will do all this automatically for you.. There is a concept of heartbeat. This would ensure that if heartbeat is not coming from a particular client, "disconnect" event would be fired automatically. 

Search for "heartbeat" on this page. https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO

Answer (score 1):

You would need to implement your own logic to do that.

Since you already have the client registering presence you could:

- maintain a persistent connection via websockets
- implement a polling/keep alive algorithm between your clients and server

Comment: OK. Thanks!!. Is there any reference link, which will help me in doing so.